# How to use a generic union type in a mapped type with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to generate a mapped type with a generic union type.

Consider the **working** example below

```
type Keys = "container" | "body" | "button"

type Styles = { [K in Keys]: CSSProperties }
```

This works as expected. But, if I try to make the Styles type take a generic and do the same thing it falls apart. For example

```js
type Styles<Keys> = { [K in Keys]: CSSProperties }

const styles: Styles<"container" | "body" | "button"> = {...}
```

This errors with

```
(type parameter) Keys in type Styles<Keys>
Type 'Keys' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
Type 'Keys' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.ts(2322)
```

I would expect it to work the same as the very first example.

[I've created a CodeSandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/4lw8v17qqx)

*(Click the open in editor button after following the link to see the errors)*

Comment: I've run your example on codesandbox.io and it does not throw any errors

Comment: You need to [constrain the generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `Keys` to valid key types, as in `type Styles<Keys extends keyof any> = ...`

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, that solved it.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek the example compiles and runs in CodeSandbox but there are definitely Typescript Errors. You might have to open the example in edit mode to see those errors in the editor though.

Answer (score 1):

I have created mapper for that and it looks like that:

```
export type TypesToObjectMapper<Union extends string | number | symbol, T> = {
    [Prop in Union]: T;
};
```

And use exaple:

```
export type RequestMethodType = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
type TestType = TypesToObjectMapper<RequestMethodType, boolean>;
```

Result:

```
type SignalRSettings = {
    GET: boolean;
    POST: boolean;
    PUT: boolean;
    DELETE: boolean;
}
```